# Filter Product Collection By Another Attribute In Product Collection eg 'attribX', array('gt' => 'attrib-Y')

Tags: collection, filter, product-collection, collection-filtering

When using product collections like so:

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq'=>''));
```

Is it possible to use addAttributeToFilter on an attribute relative to another attribute? e.g. Can I filter special_price greater than price with something like

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('gt'=>'price'));
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve this using `addExpressionAttributeToSelect`. See class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` for this.
You can try something like this:

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('difference', '(IF ({{special_price}} > {{price}} , 1, 0))', array('special_price', 'price'));
```

This will add a new "column" named `difference` to the select that has the value 1 if the special price is bigger than the price. Now all you have to do is filter by that column.

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->having('difference = ?', 1);
```

Comment: Good, simple solution, but if you need optimal query performance, it's better to avoid `HAVING`

Comment: I don't think it works otherwise

Comment: My solution is less straightforward, but seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Zend_Db_Expr` to use raw SQL instead of values. But with product collections, you have to be careful because the query is different if the flat product index is enabled

### EAV (flat index turned off or admin area)

Here we need to add a filter for the second attribute as well because the attributes to be *selected* will be loaded in a second query and you have no access to it otherwise. Choose something that's always true, I went for 'notnull'. The joined attribute table can be referenced with "at_" + attribute code:

```
$_productCollection
    ->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['notnull' => true])
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'special_price',
        ['lt' => new Zend_Db_Expr('at_price.value')]
    );
```

### Using flat index

With the flat index you can access any attribute directly that is included in the flat index (i.e. "Used in product listing"):

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'special_price',
    ['lt' => new Zend_Db_Expr('price')]
);
```

### Universal solution

Using `addExpressionAttributeToSelect()` as suggested by @Marius, we can make sure that all attributes used in the expression are available, without having to add a dummy filter (both are just workarounds but work equally well). Then we only need to use a different expression, depending on `isEnabledFlat()`:

```
$priceExpression = $_productCollection()->isEnabledFlat()
    ? new Zend_Db_Expr('price')
    : new Zend_Db_Expr('at_price.value');
$_productCollection
    ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('difference', '(IF ({{special_price}} > {{price}} , 1, 0))', array('special_price', 'price'));
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'special_price',
        ['lt' => $priceExpression]
    );
```

Note that we don't actually use `difference` in the filter, because `WHERE` is executed before the value is calculated. But this also means, MySQL can optimize the query better than with `HAVING`, which is executed last.