# How to compare a product attributes with product Notify stock Qty in Magento Collection

Tags: product, product-collection

I want to get product collection which has **notify_stock_qty** greater than **total_available_qty** (custom product attribute). So I used below code-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('status',1)
                                                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                       ->joinField('notify_stock_qty',
                                                         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                                                         'notify_stock_qty',
                                                         'product_id=entity_id',
                                                         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                                                         'left')
                                                        ->addAttributeToFilter('notify_stock_qty', array ('gt' => new Zend_Db_Expr('total_available_qty') ) );
```

This showing below error-

```
a:5:{i:0;s:870:"SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, `at_notify_stock_qty`.`notify_stock_qty` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '273') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '273') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1)
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_notify_stock_qty` ON (at_notify_stock_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_notify_stock_qty.stock_id=1) WHERE (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1') AND (at_notify_stock_qty.notify_stock_qty > total_available_qty)
```

I tried below links but did not worked-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148180/how-do-i-compare-2-different-fields-in-magento-in-a-collection

[Filter Product Collection By Another Attribute In Product Collection eg 'attribX', array('gt' => 'attrib-Y')](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10440/filter-product-collection-by-another-attribute-in-product-collection-eg-attribx)

I am not sure what is wrong there ?

**Solution**---
This worked for me---

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('status',1)
                                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('total_available_qty')
                                                       ->addFieldToFilter('total_available_qty',array('gteq'=>0))
                                                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                       ->joinField('notify_stock_qty',
                                                         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                                                         'notify_stock_qty',
                                                         'product_id=entity_id',
                                                         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                                                         'left');
        $collection ->getSelect()->where('`at_notify_stock_qty`.`notify_stock_qty` > `at_total_available_qty`.`value`');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to filter by the **total_available_qty** attribute you should use:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('total_available_qty', array('lt' => new Zend_Db_Expr('notify_stock_qty')))
```

In **MySQL** it is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

When you were calling:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('notify_stock_qty', array('gt' => new Zend_Db_Expr('total_available_qty')));
```

**total_available_qty** is a column alias for **at_total_available_qty.value**.

So if you plan on using attributes in the **WHERE** condition you should use them with the full table reference.

Comment: Hello Marina, Thanks for the reply. I have already resolved this issue. I will update its answer soon, ali'll bit busy now.

Comment: Here is the new mission for you if you accept it, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97767/supplier-is-not-being-shown-in-grid-filter-in-catalog-product-grid

Comment: I have added my solution in my question above.